# insert special character in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

When, I am trying to insert "I am Fine & How are you". And, when i look back to the database, then i see, only "I am Fine" is inserted rest words are trimmed from that sentence. This problem also arise, when i use **'** in between the sentence.

My sample code is

```
$title= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
mysql_query("insert into table_db(TITLE) values ('".$title."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

I searched on google, and found many solution, but, my problem still unsolved.
help will be appreciated !!

varchar(300)

Comment: What happens if you try to insert `I am Fine How are you`, without the ampersand?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the proper method to make that string "safe" for the query, so it's unlikely to be the query itself causing the problem. What is the type/size of the `TITLE` field? If it's a char(9) or varchar(9), then that would just hold your "I am Fine" and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with PHP, but this kind of problem would generally be solved by using **bound parameters** (a.k.a. "bind variables") and letting the underlying database API worry about special characters.

By escaping and concatenating strings yourself, you are essentially betting that escape function is up-to-date relative to your database of choice, which appears not to be the case here.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_tbl values('$title')");
```

instead of

```
mysql_query("insert into table_db(TITLE) values ('".$title."')") or die(mysql_error());
```

my below code works fine

```
<?php 
    mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    mysql_select_db('core');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo $title=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO test_tbl values(null,'','','$title')");
    }
?>


<html>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
            <input type="text" name="title">
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```